# How to round off timestamp in milliseconds to nearest seconds?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to round off the current timestamp in milliseconds to seconds?

If this is the current timestamp in milliseconds I have -

```
1384393612958
```

The if I am rounding off to nearest second then it will be like this -

```
Time in MS rounded off to nearest Second = 1384393612000
```

Comment: This looks more like a programming question. Probably, you are not dividing by $1000$ properly.

Comment: Shouldn't the nearest second be $1384393613000$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are programming this, then this is assuming that all fractions disappear, so 8/5 = 1.6 = 1 (in programming). In that case, the second easiest way to round something is to add half of unit you want to round to and then divide by that unit. If you want to round to the nearest 1000ms, and your timestamp is is x, then do (x+500ms)/1000ms and you will get your answer in terms of seconds.

Comment: what about this? use an integer number, divide by one thousand (to shave off the milli-seconds), and then multiple by thousand to get the ms value rounded to seconds.

Comment: @user2809564 that would work, but it will always round down, not round. I am not sure if thats what you want, but if it is, then that is fine (unless you are using a weird programming language)

Comment: What do you mean by round down and not round?

Comment: @user2809564 rounding down 1.8 = 1. Rounding 1.8 = 2. Rounding down means getting rid of the decimal, and rounding is changing the number to the nearest integer